# how to compare multiple columns and print not matching columns using unix shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ksh

I have two files.

```
File1
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17

File2
col1,col2,col03,col4,col5,col06,col7
col11,col12,col13,col14,col015,col16,col17
```

I want to compare the second file with the first file line by line and then column by column and print the message something like

```
On line number 1, field#3 is different(col03)
On line number 1, field#6 is different(col06)
On line number 2, field#5 is different(col15)
```

Also is it possible to skip some columns specifically. Thanks

Edit:
Like this script

```
$ awk -F"," 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' f1 f2

    FNR==NR is performed when reading the first file.
    {a[$1]; next} stores in a[] the lines of the first file and goes to the next line.
    $1 in a is evaluated when looping through the second file. It checks if the current line is within the a[] array.
```

gives me the second file line. But I dont want to compare line but specific columns from file 1 with file 2

Comment: Did you try anything? Please show some work done. Not my downvotes, btw. _Also is it possible to skip some columns specifically_ Sure is, please specify with a testable sample what you mean by this.

Comment: I tried the other solutions which are already there for awk. But there they mention specific columns, I am not sure how to tweak the awk to incorporate the columns from two files. Thanks for your comment, appreciate it. and upvoted

Comment: IS there always the same amount of records and fields?

Comment: Thank you James Brown, yes currently I am assuming the same number of records each time. Basically I will be comparing lot of files from one directory with other directory and checking difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -F, '                          # set delimiter
NR==FNR {                             # process file1
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # iterate all fields
        a[FNR][i]=$i                  # hash to 2D array
    next
}
{                                     # process file2
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # iterate fields
        if($i!=a[FNR][i])             # compare and output if needed
            printf "On line number %d, field#%d is different(%s)\n",FNR,i,$i
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
On line number 1, field#3 is different(col03)
On line number 1, field#6 is different(col06)
On line number 2, field#5 is different(col015)
```

This solution pretty much expects that the record and field counts in both files are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot James Brown. It helped me a lot,  since for loop is there , I can also skip particular columns with continue, Sincere thanks for your help.

Comment: Also thanks a lot for your comments in the code :) it helped me to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, one more of doing it could be, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    arr[FNR OFS i]=$i
  }
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(arr[FNR OFS i]!=$i){
      print "On line number " FNR ", field#" i" is different("$i")")"
    }
  }
}
' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                       ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS=","                 ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma.
}
FNR==NR{                     ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){        ##Starting a for loop till number of fields here.
    arr[FNR OFS i]=$i        ##Creating an array with index of current line number and field number and value is current field.
  }
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){        ##Starting for loop till number of fields here.
    if(arr[FNR OFS i]!=$i){  ##Checking condition if current field value is NOT equals to array with index of current line and field number.
      print "On line number " FNR ", field#" i" is different("$i")")"
                             ##Printing statement with field and line number as per OP request.
    }
  }
}
' file1 file2                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thank you RavinderSingh13 for your help. I was trying to run the command but was getting error. Now saw this updated solution and it worked. Just I didn't understand the line arr[FNR OFS i]=$i , could you please elaborate how does it work please, thank you for your help

Comment: @ForeverLearner, solution is tested and worked fine for me, I have added detailed explanation too in my solution now, please do let me know in case of any queries here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 , thanks a lot sir , it worked and thank you for adding the explanation :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I have loved your happy learning and cheers comment, not sure why did you delete it. Sorry and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks sir for your motivation again :)

Answer (score 1):

Another awk using paste command.

```
$ cat forever1.txt
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17

$ cat forever2.txt
col1,col2,col03,col4,col5,col06,col7
col11,col12,col13,col14,col015,col16,col17

$ paste -d, forever1.txt forever2.txt | \
awk -F, ' { nf=NF/2; for(i=1;i<=nf;i++) { if($i!=$(nf+i)) print "On line number " NR ",field " i," is different(" $i ")" ; } } '
On line number 1,field 3  is different(col3)
On line number 1,field 6  is different(col6)
On line number 2,field 5  is different(col15)

$
```

Join the 2 files using the same delimiter with "join" command, then you always get even number of fields. Pipe the output to another awk and compare first half with second one in a loop

Comment: thank you for your inputs but somehow I am getting different output on other delimeters and loop. Still trying to understand it.

Comment: @ForeverLearner.. can you share sample data

Comment: Different delimiter is working, sorry there was typo from my side on the command, thank you for your help and sharing the new way :)